# Прошу обьяснить операцию умножения блоков в aes-gcm

Tags: c++, криптография, aes

Здравствуйте в данный момент я пытаюсь понять реализацию шифрования AES-GCM на c++ и я совершенно не понимаю одну функцию и так.
Вот описание функции в официальном документе NIST
[image]

А вот реализация

```
static void xor_block(aes_uchar *dst, const aes_uchar *src)
{
    aes_uint *d = (aes_uint *) dst;
    aes_uint *s = (aes_uint *) src;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
    *d++ ^= *s++;
}
/* Multiplication in GF(2^128) */
static void gf_mult(const aes_uchar *x, const aes_uchar *y, aes_uchar *z)
{
    aes_uchar v[16];
    int i, j;

    memset(z, 0, 16); /* Z_0 = 0^128 */
    memcpy(v, y, 16); /* V_0 = Y */

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (x[i] & 1 << (7 - j)) {
                /* Z_(i + 1) = Z_i XOR V_i */
                xor_block(z, v);
            } else {
                /* Z_(i + 1) = Z_i */
            }

            if (v[15] & 0x01) {
                /* V_(i + 1) = (V_i >> 1) XOR R */
                shift_right_block(v);
                /* R = 11100001 || 0^120 */
                v[0] ^= 0xe1;
            } else {
                /* V_(i + 1) = V_i >> 1 */
                shift_right_block(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Меня интересует фрагмент где `Zi+1 = Zi XOR Vi if xi =1`.
Функция `xor_blocks` выполняет операцию XOR не на биты как сказано в NIST а на все 16 байт именно это мне и непонятно, я не понимаю как обработаются конкретные биты если обработать все 16 байт?
P.S (Пример кода взят отсюда https://github.com/michaeljclark/aes-gcm/blob/master/src/aes-gcm.c)

Comment: «все 16 байт» это и есть «все 128 бит» не очень понятно, что именно здесь смущает... если что, то каждое значение `Zi` — это 128-битное число...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Мне не понятны циклы `for` то есть идёт сначало цикл на блок 16 байт затем обрабатывается каждый байт циклом по 8-мь (биты), и тут я не понимаю если `x = 1` то он выполняется операция `xor_blocks` несколько раз над одним байтом? `if (x[i] & 1 << (7 - j))` проверяет равен ли бит 1 и если вернёт `true` то идёт xor_blocks но `true` вернётся много раз и соответственно будет много выполнений `xor_blocks`. Так на сколько тогда увеличиться каждый байт? У меня такое чувство что я что-то упустил.

Comment: два цикла вместе проходят по всем битам числа `x` один раз. это просто способ записать один цикл из доки... аналогично можно было бы сделать одним циклом как-то так: `for(int i=0; i<127; i++) if(x[i/8]&(1<<(7-i%8)))…`. дальше всё как написано: если очередной бит в числе `x` равен `1`, то всё число `z` xor'ится с числом `v`. в противном случае — оно не меняется. `xor_blocks` — это и есть операция сложения (⊕) в поле GF(2^128). Она выполняется для каждого ненулевого бита числа `x`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо обьяснив циклы вы мне очень помогли. Вы могли-бы сделать ваш коментарий ответом и я засчитал-бы его как решение

Comment: гм... ответ скорее всего писать не буду т.к. мало понимаю, о чём был вопрос... можешь сам набросать, если разобрался...